# cannot make changes in context persist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a simple 3-tier MVC app, and cannot make context changes persist. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(UserDto user)
    {
        userService.Register(user);
        return Ok("profile");
    }
```

Service:

```
    public void Register(UserDto userDto)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.FirstName = userDto.FirstName;
        user.LastName = userDto.LastName;
        user.Type = (UserType) userDto.Type;
        unitOfWork.UserRepository.AddAsync(user);
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(params T[] entities)
    {
        await dbSet.AddRangeAsync(entities);
        await SaveChanges();
    }

    private async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Using my debugger, i found out that the dbset.AddRangeAsync does add the entity i set in the request into my dbContext. The problem is, on the next request, the entity is gone from the dbContext, and also does not appear in my database.Can somebody can explain me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you happen to use localdb?

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't know if i use localdb. For the database i use SQLServerExplorer. It created a .mdf file in my Users/{user} folder.

Comment: Yep, localdb. Please look for other questions on similar localdb problems. Also, as a by-catch, look at the answer and make your code async-all-the-way.

Comment: I just noticed that i do not have a .mdf file in my solution, although my database does exist(it is empty since changes do not persist). I am using EF Core if it matters. Is it normal for the .mdf to not exist or could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your add method is asynchronous.other methods that call this method must be asynchronous.

```
 public async Task Register(UserDto userDto)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.FirstName = userDto.FirstName;
        user.LastName = userDto.LastName;
        user.Type = (UserType) userDto.Type;
       await unitOfWork.UserRepository.AddAsync(user);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserDto user)
    {
       await userService.Register(user);
        return Ok("profile");
    }
```

Comment: True, but this is not the real issue. `SaveChanges` should work nonetheless.

Comment: In the controller, userService.Register (user) execute After the request completion,and at this time the dbcontext is disposed

Comment: You do have a point here, but this should throw an exception, which isn't OP's experience, *dbset.AddRangeAsync does add the entity*. It could be yet another localdb confusion Nearly always when I see "saved successfully" + "not in the database" localdb is involved.

Comment: After some more debugging, i find this: if, inside the Configure method in startup.cs, i add an entity in the context and save the changes, then the AddRangeAsync will also be saved. Otherwise, it doesn't. Do you have any idea what to do? I don't even know how to search for this bug on other SO questions.